# How are those connectors called? (see images)

Tags: connector, identification, plug

How are those connectors called?

[image: http://www.keelog.com/images/kl_mod22.jpg][image]

Comment: @Andyaka How do you call those small plugs on around the wires on the second image

Comment: try molex's website - it's pretty clear info the first time I thought

Answer (score 5):

It is a widely-used 4-pin female connector, a **crimp housing** with four female **crimp terminals** inserted.  There are many manufacturers that make a connector like this, but Molex makes one [Part Number: 50-57-9004](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0050579004_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml) (SL™ Crimp Housing, Single Row, Version A, Non-polarized, 4 Circuits) in the SL Modular connector line.  You can [order this housing on Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=50-57-9004).

You can easily crimp these terminals yourself with a low cost hand crimping tool if you want to make cable assemblies with this kind of connector.  You'd need to buy a bag of female crimp terminals to use, then after crimping the wires, you insert the terminals into place in the housing.

Comment: don't forget the gold-plating

Comment: Are you sure the 'Digi-Key' housing is the one in the pictures?

Comment: Since these connect to header pins, shouldn't these alos be properly referred to as "header connectors"?

Comment: @Shabab it is a "header connector" when assembled, but the product consists of separately ordered parts: a _crimp housing_ and the _crimp terminals_ -- where the _crimp terminals_ can be shared between many different types of connector form factors (different _housings_)

Comment: @user30289 DigiKey is just the distributor, if that's not the connector you ask about you should specify it in the question

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that Molex manufactures these connectors, part of their SL line - non-polarized housing, in particular.  In my experience, however, they're far more commonly termed "DuPont connectors".  (People more often relate latched connectors to Molex.)  They are also colloquially referred to as "jumper connectors" or "pin header connectors" on occasion, which is a bit vague, but since 0.1" pitch is most common, the terms are more often than not in allusion to these guys.

**Edit:**  Almost forgot, the proper name, I believe is "Mini-PV", originally produced by DuPont, hence "DuPont connector", even though they made others.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for 4 pin Molex connector, you'll find what you are looking for. Molex isn't the proper name for it, but the company is like the Kleenex of connectors.

Comment: I can't find those type of "Kleenex connectors", I can only find "Kleenex Ultra toilet roll" stuff... How do you call those small plugs on around the wires on the second image?

Comment: Make some effort and search in google it.

Comment: they're crimp on , they're for square pins, they're ....gold plated...they're.....female header connectors.... they're *'female crimp pins'* http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1930

Comment: That's the funniest comment I have ever read on this website.

Comment: 4-pin Molex, to me and any other computer enthusiasts, as the typical cable supplying +12V and +5V lines (along with two COM wires) to peripheral devices in ATX PSUs.